# Why join won't work in this each statement

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a method that capitalizes the first letter of each word in a string.

```
def capitalize(string)
  arr1 = string.split(" ")
  arr2 = []
  arr1.each do |i|
    arr2 << i.split(//)
  end
  arr2.each do |i|
    i[0].upcase!
    i = i.join
  end
  arr2.join(" ")
end
```

In my second `each` statement, the first letter of each word is successfully capitalized and I get something like this:

```
[["A", "a", "a"], ["A", "a", "a", "a"]]
```

I want to join each word together, but `i = i.join` does nothing and `i.join!` throws an error, undefined method. I tested `["A", "a", "a"].join`, and this produces the desired result. I'm confused as to why this isn't working in my method, especially when `upcase` works and this doesn't.

Can you explain how my thinking is wrong in this case and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is you're trying to modify `i` while inside an `each` block, but as `i` is a local variable, it has no effect on the original.

What you want is:

```
arr2.collect! do |i|
  i[0].upcase!
  i.join
end
```

This rewrites the contents of the array.

What you can do, though, is roll this up into a simple `gsub`:

```
def capitalize(string)
  string.gsub(/\b([a-z])\B/) do |m|
    $1.upcase
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this code here:

```
arr1.each do |i|
    arr2 << i.split(//)
end
```

You are splitting each character of each word from the first array. This is essentially going to give you an array of array's. If you put this block in after your second loop, you can see the structure:

```
arr2.each do |i|
    puts("[")
        i.each do |x|
            puts(x)
        end
        puts("]")
end
```

For a solution, can do something like so:

```
def self.capitalizeB(string)
    return string.split(" ").each { |i| i[0] = i[0].upcase }.join(" ")
end
```